# Get first value of data into an array for each unique date

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following below is a data object, how do I iterate through this object with javascript to get one "value" field into an array per each unique date?

I know how to get all of the data but I need to get one for each unique date (time can be ignored in this case)

```
{
  name: "test", 
  data: Array(200)
}

data: Array(200) 
0: {
  @id: "p23o"
  code: "02"
  dateTime: "2018-12-12T04:38:00Z"
  value: -0.645
}  
1: {
  @id: "p453o"
  code: "02"
  dateTime: "2018-12-12T07:48:00Z"
  value: -0.3645
} 
2: {
  @id: "p4423o"
  code: "032"
  dateTime: "2018-12-11T07:13:00Z"
  value: -0.645
} 
+ 198 more objects
```

The array needs to be containing one value data for each day. How does one go through and interate this data into an array? What are the best practices or proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried along with the desired output.

Comment: It would be better if you shared some of the code you have tried so far, and the results it returns. Also, you could be a bit more specific on what is the result you expect, an array with the "value" values?

Comment: As @Vivendo says, it expects to get unique record from each date..

Comment: Yes, @AndreiTodorut, I just don't understand if he wants to filter it, or if he also wants to map it, or if he wants to accumulate the values for each date, or if he wants to group the values. And if he wants to filter/accumulate, how does he want to do it?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut, nearly what I need, the above is a multidimensional array, with {name and data} being in the first (JSON) format. The data is an array inside the data field of the first array (JSON). Is there a way to also get the value and dateTime into two separate arrays?

Comment: @Vivendo i updated the post

Comment: @AndreiTodorut any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date` to cast your `string` date into `Date` object, then create the date without time.

**Please follow the code bellow:**

```
// data will be the variable containing your response
var uniqueData = {};
data.forEach(item => {
   var date = new Date(item.dateTime);  
   var onlyDaysTime = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 
       date.getDate());
   var key = onlyDaysTime.toString();

   if(typeof uniqueData[key] === 'undefined') {
      uniqueData[key] = [];
   }
   uniqueData[key].push(item);
})

for(key in uniqueData) {
  console.log(uniqueData[key]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[object Object] {
  code: "02",
  dateTime: "2018-12-12T04:38:00Z",
  id: "p23o",
  value: -0.645
}, [object Object] {
  code: "02",
  dateTime: "2018-12-12T07:48:00Z",
  id: "p453o",
  value: -0.3645
}]
[[object Object] {
  code: "032",
  dateTime: "2018-12-11T07:13:00Z",
  id: "p4423o",
  value: -0.645
}]
```

**Working fiddle:** https://jsbin.com/juwekiduju/edit?js,console

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for the help, is there a way to get just the date and value into two separate arrays like [dateTime, dateTime] and [value, value] etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to store the object corresponding to each unique date in an object accumulator and then get all the values from this object using `Object.values()`

```js
let data = [{ "@id": "p23o", code: "02", dateTime: "2018-12-12T04:38:00Z", value: -0.645 } , { "@id": "p453o", code: "02", dateTime: "2018-12-12T07:48:00Z", value: -0.3645 } , { "@id": "p4423o", code: "032", dateTime: "2018-12-11T07:13:00Z", value: -0.645 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      let date = o.dateTime.substring(0,10);
      if(!(date in r)) r[date] = {...o};
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```